# nonparametric sample size calculation

Tags: nonparametric, sample-size, stata

I am running into conflicting information regarding a running a sample size calculation for a nonparametric dataset.  I will be collected data from a medical procedure that gives pressure readings based on bladder pressures.  these are not known to be normally distributed and they are from patients before and after an intervention, I plan to use a wilcoxon sign rank test to analyze data on the back end. I am wondering the best way to calculate a sample size.  My study will have relatively low numbers (less than 100 patients, but is matched).  What is the best way to do this? is it even necessary?

Comment: Are you asking for a non-parametric power calculation? Given a probability of not making a type II error, an estimation of irreducible noise and some criterion for making a type I error, what is the smallest sample size needed to detect some specified effect size -- all non-parametrically. Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: The size of the effect would have to be expressed in terms of ranks.

Comment: The answer to the statistical question is, use simulation unless you expect the sample size to be fairly large (in the hundreds).  The answer to the Stata question is outside the scope of this site.  If you are interested in the statistical question, then please provide more information about your situation, such as descriptions of the likely distributions and the intended confidence and power of the study.

Comment: @Bruce not necessarily, but then power would depend on the distribution and the particular class of alternatives considered.

Comment: There's no such thing as a nonparametric dataset.  There are only nonparametric statistical tests and estimators.

Comment: In addition to Frank's comment. Probably a reference like Zhao (2008) "[Sample size calculation for the Wilcoxon–Mann–Whitney test adjusting for ties](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.2912)" will be helpful.